# Edit/upload a GAE app code from third party application

Tags: google-app-engine

I want to create a Google App Engine application using Python that would upload GAE App code.

I want to know that which Google Service do I need to use to connect to Google App Engine. I know that it is possible to do this by third party applications as https://codenvy.com/ is doing same.

Comment: don't think there is an api to create a GAE app.

Comment: https://codenvy.com/ is doing that. So there should be a way to do that.

Comment: and you are sure its creating a new app and not only updating an existing one? what i believe it does is create it locally but i doubt it can create an app in the cloud.

Comment: check here: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=E4SscNHNr5g it only redirects you to the screen where you can create the app.

Answer (score 0):

there is no api to create a GAE app.
you need to create it first and then you can upload your code.

Comment: yes, that's what I want. Edited the question. How to connect to "GAE Application Console". Is it related to OAuth permissions?